# Next Js: Module not found: Can't resolve '@/lib/db'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I am new to react & next and working with nextjs 13.5.3

I created a file at src/lib/db.js

importing in inner pages/api like this

```
import {connectionSrt} from "@/lib/db";
```

but which I run the application get this error

```
Module not found: Can't resolve '@/lib/db'
```

but when import like this, works fine

```
import {connectionSrt} from "../../../lib/db";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Typescript for React/Next.js project, you should consider tsconfig.json setting.
All of imports with alias(@) are configured by config.json setting.

Therefore, the setting should look like below.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Actually, do not care all of settings, but focus on "paths".
It makes Next.js to enable imports by alias(@).
Hope this helpful for you.